# SQL Pivot / Unpivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I have the below result and I have tried to *unpivot* to move all columns to rows and have the values from Quarter as columns, but no matter how much I try, I do not get the result I am looking for.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction because the **pivot/unpivot** confuses me alot.

Current data:

```
Qarter    Fatal incidents    PSC Detentions    Oil spill to Sea
Q1 2021   0                  0                 1
Q2 2021   1                  1                 1
Q3 2021   0                  0                 0
```

Desired result is

```
                     Q1 2021     Q2 2021     Q3 2021
Fatal incidents      0           1           0
PSC Detentions       0           1           0
Oil spill to sea     1           1           0
```

Comment: what is your desired output ?

Comment: Fatal Incidents, PSC Detention, PSC Insp, Oil spill, Near miss, SIRE, CDI, LTI,RWC, MTC and Man hours as rows
Q1 2021, Q2 2021, Q3 2021 and Q4 2021 as columns

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: I am sorry Dale for posting an image, I am not that familiar with how to present data in a good manner here, that is why it did it

Comment: I have updated with table looking data

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

You seem to want all the columns, except for the second one, which turns into two:

```
select t.quarter, t.psc_detentions, t.oil_spill_sea, . . .,
       v.marks, v.q
from t cross apply
     (values ('Fatal incidents', Fatal_incidents)
     ) v(q, marks);
```

Note that for this simple example, you don't really even need `apply`:

```
select t.quarter, t.psc_detentions, t.oil_spill_sea, . . .,
       Fatal_incidents as marks, 'Fatal incidents' as q
from t;
```

I am guessing, though, that you have multiple columns that you want to treat this way, which is why I suggest `apply`.

Comment: This still shows all columns as columns. I want all columns to become rows, and the rows to become columns

Comment: @Pochen . . . Your question has two table images in it (I should add that images are discouraged for such purposes; use text tables or DDL).  Presumably, the first is the source data and the second is the desired results.  If not, your question is unclear and I can vote to close.

Comment: I have updated the post with data in a structured way. Sorry for confusion

Answer (score 0):

You can try to Unpivot the data first and then Pivot.

```
select      ca.Type
            , max(case when t.Qarter = 'Q1 2021' then ca.Value end) as [Q1 2021]
            , max(case when t.Qarter = 'Q2 2021' then ca.Value end) as [Q2 2021]
            , max(case when t.Qarter = 'Q3 2021' then ca.Value end) as [Q3 2021]
from        dbo.Table1                                             as t
cross apply (   values ('Fatal incidents', [Fatal incidents])
                       , ('PSC Detentions', [PSC Detentions])
                       , ('Oil spill to Sea', [Oil spill to Sea])) as ca ([Type], [Value])
group by    ca.Type
```

the Cross Apply will Unpivot, and the aggregates will Pivot the data for you.